# How to override a Zend class?

Tags: magento2, overrides, zend-framework

I want to override a Zend class (`Zend_Date`). In Magento 1, I used to put `Date.php` in `app/code/community/Zend`  and Magento itself used to do the rest. But now, there is no such directory. How can I override that class?

---

**Edit:**
I installed [Magento_SampleNewPage](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-newpage)  module and it shows `Hello world!` message properly when I go to `http://domain.com/newpage`. I edited `composer.json` and added my `Date.php`  to it:

```
{
  "name": "magento/sample-module-newpage",
  "description": "A Magento 2 module that creates a new page",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "Zend/Date.php" , "registration.php"  ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Magento\\SampleNewPage\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

But still, it doesn't work. When I instantiate a new `Zend_Date` , it's from `vendor/Magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Date.php`  not my `Zend_Date`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no "local code pool override" mechanism anymore. Instead you can use **preferences** in `di.xml` for any class that is instantiated by the Magento object manager, i.e. used via Dependency Injection in Magento classes. This is the equivalent to a class rewrite in Magento 1.

But for classes like `Zend_Date` where this is not the case, this is not possible.

However you could create a composer package that loads your own `Zend_Date` class before the real one is loaded via autoloading:

#### composer.json

```
{
    "name": "your/custom-date",
    "autoload": {
      "files": ["src/lib/Zend/Date.php"]
    }
}
```

#### src/lib/Zend/Date.php

```
class Zend_Date
{
    ...
}
```

**[Edit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136156/how-to-override-a-zend-class#comment184785_136221)**: After you edited a composer.json file, run `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloader.

Comment: using this method, do we still need to add preference in dl.xml?

Comment: No, as I said,`di.xml` cannot be used with classes not instantiated by the Magento object manager. This method loads your Zend_Date class instead of the original one (same class name!), so it is similar to using `app/code/local` in Magento 1

Comment: I want to override this class everywhere in magento, in a way that in no place, magento uses its own Zend_Date class.

Comment: Yes, that's what this is doing.

Comment: @fschmengler  didn't work. I edited my question. take a look at it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: After you edited a composer.json file, run `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloader.

Comment: @fschmengler  Worked. Thanks. Just one more question: Is there any way to do it without composer?

Comment: I can't think of any other way, sorry. But Magento 2 always uses the composer autoloader, even if you did not install it using composer. So it should always be possible in some way.

Comment: @fschmengler Nothing to be sorry about. You've been a great help. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a proper solution ? I need to do the same with Zend\Validator\Hostname in order to add the last TDL

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, we shouldn't try to override a Zend class on this way. **We should create a new class, this class will extends from `Zend_Date`**. And then, try to override some Zend Date methods in your class as you want.

Comment: I want to change the output of `toString`  method. If the way you're talking about can do this, Please explain how can I do it. Thanks .

Comment: how to increase captcha size for forgot password and customer login page programmatically.Any idea do you have related it please tell me.

Comment: @hiteshbalpande should check here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141976/33057

Comment: while I agree with you, there are reasons you may want to do this. Patching known issues for example.
The question is how, not if you should.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like an easier solution is this

Modify Magento 2 `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    [...]
    ,
    "files": [
        [...],
        "lib/Zend/Http/Response.php"
    ]
},
```

Copy the `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Response.php` to `lib/Zend/Http/Response.php`

Then run `composer dump-autoload`

Warning: You are overriding entire class. But this might suit your need.