# Composer autoload doesn't work

Tags: magento2, overrides, composer, zend-framework

This is a follow up question from [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/136156/24417). I want to override a Zend class using composer autoload. It used to work, but not anymore.
This is content of my `composer.json`  file:

```
{
  "name": "magento/sample-module-newpage",
  "description": "A Magento 2 module that creates a new page",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ,"Zend/Date.php"],
    "psr-4": {
      "Magento\\SampleNewPage\\": ""
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0"
  }

}
```

If I run this command at root of my websit (where `app`,`vendor`,... directories exist), I get this:

```
composer  dumpautoload
Generating autoload files
```

And then nothing happens. It used to add my `Date.php` file to end of `vendor/composer/autoload_files.php`. What should I do?

P.S: Mudule is installed and is working correctly.