# Magento 2: How to Change Default Captcha Font, Color & Background

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, captcha

In Mangeto 2 We have default Captcha, which is not easily readable.

So how to change/customize Font Name it's Color & Background

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Color & Background

Magento builds its Model Captcha which extends from `Zend_Captcha_Image` class. So, in your case, we should override `Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel` class.

```
<preference for="Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel"
            type="Vendor\Module\Model\DefaultModel"/>
```

We need to override `_generateImage` method.

```
protected function _generateImage($id, $word)
{
      ......
      $w     = $this->getWidth();
      $h     = $this->getHeight();
      $fsize = $this->getFontSize();
      ......
}
```

We can remove the generation noise:

[image]

### Custom Font

Add new font to the default config:

*app/code/Company/Module/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <captcha translate="label">
            <fonts>
                <arial>
                    <label>Arial</label>
                    <path>CustomFont/Arial.ttf</path>
                </arial>
            </fonts>
        </captcha>
    </default>
</config>
```

Add our custom font: `lib/internal/CustomFont/Arial.ttf`

[image]

**Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-captcha/Helper/Data.php::getFonts()` to see more details.**

Comment: Hi @Khoa. Thanks for answer. Appreciated. Can you please give frontend captcha screenshot as well? How it looks like & how can change/set different background with Font match color

Comment: @AnkitShah updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @Khoa File is here `vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Captcha\Image.php` How to Orverwrite this file? I already removed noise from here. Where to put in `app\code`?

Comment: @AnkitShah you should read here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136156/how-to-override-a-zend-class

Comment: @AnkitShah why you need to override the Zend library?

Comment: Because, If suppose Currently i'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2. When Magento Upgrade it's version then this file be changed right?

Comment: So it will be `magento\app\code\Community\Zend\Image.php` ?

Comment: `this file be changed right? ` what file?

Comment: It means while upgrading Magento is Upgrading Core File & Fixes Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47802/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-ankit-shah).

Comment: _generateImage this function not there in above file

Comment: @jafarpinjar I think it should be `protected function generateImage`

Comment: that is also not there, i checked. this is the path right? Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel

Comment: `Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel`  should extend from `\Zend\Captcha\Image`?

Answer (score 0):

For Captcha customise I think you need change in this file :

```
magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php
```

Comment: Yes you are right @Nikunj. But how to orverride this file?

Answer (score 0):

in Magento ver. 2.4.4 just edit :
/vendor/magento/module-captcha/Model/DefaultModel.php