# Override magento 2 default files

Tags: magento2, overrides

How to override default magento 2 file

```
vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/ExtensionAttributesProcessor.php
```

in my custom module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override a zend class](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136156/how-to-override-a-zend-class)