# Magento 2.3.3 How to change Currency decimal symbol comma to dot in arabic store view

Tags: magento2.3, multicurrency, currency-symbol, arabic

I want to change currency decimal symbol from comma to dot for Arabic store view.

Below is the solution that I tried but it's not working for all the pages like category, search page, minicart, checkout cart page its only working with product page.

```php
namespace CustomModule\CustomPriceFormat\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;

class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format
{
    private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';

    public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
    {
        $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
        if ($currencyCode) {
            $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
        } else {
            $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
        }

        $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
        $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;

        $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
                ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);

        //your main changes are gone here.....
        $decimalSymbol = '.';
        $groupSymbol = ',';

        $pos = strpos($format, ';');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
        }
        $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
        $totalPrecision = 0;
        $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
        if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
            $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
        } else {
            $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
        }
        $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
        $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
        $pos = strpos($t, '#');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
        }

        if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
            $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
        } else {
            $group = strrpos($format, '.');
        }
        $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');

        $result = [
            //TODO: change interface
            'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
            'precision' => $totalPrecision,
            'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
            'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
            'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
            'groupLength' => $group,
            'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
        ];       
        //print_r($result);
        //exit;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Any solution available that will work for every page?

Thanks

Comment: Do you change like this (https://prnt.sc/zunurl)?

Comment: I need like this https://prnt.sc/zutkui

Comment: I have one solution but you have to done changes to the core file. Because I can't try overriding that file or anything else.

Comment: I don't want to change in core file otherwise below solution working 

vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_KW.xml 

<numbers>
    <symbols numberSystem="latn">
        <decimal>.</decimal>
        <group>,</group>
        <list>;</list>
        <percentSign>%</percentSign>
        <plusSign>+</plusSign>
        <minusSign>-</minusSign>
        <exponential>E</exponential>
        <superscriptingExponent>×</superscriptingExponent>
        <perMille>‰</perMille>
        <infinity>∞</infinity>
        <nan>NaN</nan>
    </symbols>
</numbers>

Answer (score 0):

You also need to override the Zend framework for the change to be visible in all pages.

Create file and directory: `lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php`

Copy the Format.php file from `vendor....Zend/Locale/Format.php` and modify as follows:

Search for instances of `$symbols = Zend_Locale_Data::getList` and for each instance, add the following code to override the decimal symbol:

```
$symbols['decimal'] = '.';
```

For more details on how to override Zend files using composer, see:
[How to override a Zend class?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136156/how-to-override-a-zend-class)